# Unable to extract columns form the data frame pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading the json file and extracting the required columns into the csv file .Please find the below code and let me know if am wrong

```
df=pd.read_json(json_file)
df=df['Person']
data1=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['cols1','cols2','cols3','title'])

print data1

df.to_csv("ptr1.csv",index = False)
```

but i'm getting the error empty dataframe output .

Comment: `print(df.head())` and edit your question with its output.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('file.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file) 

df = json_normalize(data, 'Person')
```

Sample:

```
data = {"Person": [{ "cols1" : 1, "cols2" : "value2", "cols3" : "value1", "title" : "ptr" }]}

df = json_normalize(data, 'Person')
print (df)
   cols1   cols2   cols3 title
0      1  value2  value1   ptr
```

Comment: I have tried that option i'm getting the Keyerror ['cols1','cols2','cols3','title'] not in index

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ? Error means there are no one or more columns in `['cols1','cols2','cols3','title']`

Comment: for df.columns.tolist() -> i'm getting the error "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns' "

Comment: do you remove `df=df['Person']` ?

Comment: No , Would you like to remove that one

Comment: Yes, because you assign column to `df`, so original data are overwrite.

Comment: i Removed that one after that for print (df.columns.tolist()) -> getting output as [u'Person']

Comment: OK, then I dont understand. Do you need convert one column `Person` convert to `['cols1','cols2','cols3','title']` ? What is `print (df.head())` ? There are same nested lists?

Comment: please find the below sample json file data 
{
 "Person": [
 {   "cols1" : 1,
  "cols2" : "value2",
  "cols3" : "value1",
  "title" : "ptr"
 }
 ]
}
can you help me out how to extract the cols1...ttitle columns from the json file

Answer (score 0):

Still i'm getting the empty dataframe .Please find the below code

```
json_file = open("file.json")

df=pd.read_json(json_file)

data=json_normalize(json_file, 'Person')
print data
```

Getting output :
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []